# Access private field without getter method?

Tags: java

Here is an excerpt from JDK7 source code:

```
public String(String original) {
    this.value = original.value;
    this.hash = original.hash;
}
```

Both `value` and `hash` are `private` field. Why is `original.value` legal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [this table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

```
                   Access Levels
Modifier     | Class  | Package   |  Subclass | World
-------------+--------+-----------+-----------+--------
public       |   Y    |     Y     |     Y     |   Y
protected    |   Y    |     Y     |     Y     |   N
no modifier  |   Y    |     Y     |     N     |   N
private      |   Y  ← |     N     |     N     |   N
```

Comment: Oh ..my twin brother :) You beat me. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Access modifiers describe access for **classes**, not **instances**. Since `value` was declared in `String` class, all its members - like constructors - have unlimited access to it.

Answer (score 1):

A class can access its own private fields (even on other instances than `this`).

Answer (score 1):

```
Both value and hash are private filed. Why is original.value legal?
```

Because it is still inside String class and private variables can be accessed withing same class.

Answer (score 1):

You should really look in to the access control table

```
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World
---------------------------------------------

private     **Y**      N        N           N
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

> The private modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed in its own class.

Since it is with in the class you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Getters and setters are really for implementation outside the scope of class.
Inside a class any variable can be accessed without any restriction.